# Does myVector.erase(myPtr) delete the object pointed by myPtr?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

If I have the following code,

```
Foo *f = new Foo();
vector<Foo*> vect;
vect.push_back(f);
// do stuff
vect.erase(f);
```

Did I create a memory leak? 
I guess so, but the word *erase* gives the feeling that it is deleting it.

Writing this, I am wondering if it is not a mistake to put a pointer in a STL vector. What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you created a memory leak by that. std::vector and other containers will just remove the pointer, they won't free the memory the pointer points to.

It's not unusual to put a pointer into a standard library container. The problem, however, is that you have to keep track of deleting it when removing it from the container. A better, yet simple, way to do the above, is to use boost::shared_ptr:

```
{ 
    boost::shared_ptr<foo> f(new foo);

    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<foo> > v;
    v.push_back(f);
    v.erase(v.begin());
} /* if the last copy of foo goes out of scope, the memory is automatically freed */
```

The next C++ standard (called C++1x and C++0x commonly) will include `std::shared_ptr`. There, you will also be able to use `std::unique_ptr<T>` which is faster, as it doesn't allow copying. Using `std::unique_ptr` with containers in c++0x is similar to the `ptr_container` library in boost.

Comment: Be very careful to use boost::shared_ptr, as this answer instructs, instead of auto_ptr.  STL containers cannot be used at all with auto_ptr (the reason is a bit long to explain in this comment).

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the Boost [Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).  They are designed to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively there is the boost::ptr_vector [container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

It knows it is holding pointers that it owns and thus auto deletes them.

As a nice side affect, when accessing elements it returns a reference to the object not the pointer to make the code look nice.

```
Foo *f = new Foo();
boost::ptr_vector<Foo>  vect;
vect.push_back(f);
// do stuff
vect.erase(f);
```

Comment: Great reference, thanks for that. It just so happens that I spend the last few days refactoring containers-of-ptrs data structures, boost::indirect_iterator has been helpful but these ptr_xxx containers would be even better I think... Maybe I'll need to refactor again ;)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify why the pointer is not deleted, consider

```
std::vector<char const*> strings;
strings.push_back("hello");
strings.push_back("world");
// .erase should not call delete, pointers are to literals

std::vector<int*> arrays;
strings.push_back(new int[10]);
strings.push_back(new int[20]);
// .erase should call delete[] instead of delete

std::vector<unsigned char*> raw;
strings.push_back(malloc(1000));
strings.push_back(malloc(2000));
// .erase should call free() instead of delete
```

In general, `vector<T*>::erase` cannot guess how you'd dispose of a `T*`.

Comment: Consider what? Please tell us what we should be considering, even if only briefly. You don't seem to be erasing anything at all, and none of your pushes share any references. After thinking about it for several minutes, I thought perhaps your intent was for us to notice the issue with your `char const*`, but I'm not sure what your intent is. Please don't leave us with a cliff-hanger. -1

If I was correct about your intent, adding just a "What would that do about 'the such and such case'" would be helpful.

Comment: @Aaron: Consider whether it would be appropriate for `std::vector<T*>::erase(iter)` to call `delete *iter`,  given the examples above. And to give the answer: No. The first example calls `delete` on a string literal (should do nothing), in the second example `erase` would have to call `delete[]` and in the third case `erase` would need to call `free()`.

Comment: Right. I probably should have caught the problem with the second sample (arrays); not sure why I didn't. For the third one (malloc): I will admit that it has been so long since I have used malloc for anything that I forgot you are not supposed to mix new/free or malloc/delete. The third sample especially is why you should explain with at least a line or two; because of people like me.  ;)  Removing the -1, and if you put your comment into the answer I'll even make it a +1.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not a mistake to point a pointer into a standard container (it's a mistake to make a container of auto_ptr's however).  Yes, you do need to explicitly delete to free the memory pointed to by the individual elements, or you can use one of the boost [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 1):

vector deletes the data it contains. Since your vector contains pointers, it only deletes the pointers, not the data they may or may not point to.

It's a pretty general rule in C++ that memory is released where it was allocated. The vector did not allocate whatever your pointers point to, so it must not release it.

You probably shouldn't store pointers in your vector in the first place.
In many cases, you would be better off with something like this:

```
vector<Foo> vect;
vect.push_back(Foo());
// do stuff
vect.erase(f);
```

Of course this assumes that Foo is copyable, and that its copy constructor is not too expensive, but it avoids memory leaks, and you don't have to remember to delete the Foo object. Another approach would be to use smart pointers (such as Boost's shared_ptr), but you may not need pointer semantics at all, in which case the simple solution is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

STL containers will not free your memory. The best advice is using smart pointers, knowing that std::auto_ptr will not fit inside containers. I would recommend boost::shared_ptr, or if your compiler vendor has support for TR1 extensions (many do) you can use std::tr1::shared_ptr.

Also note that the vector will not even free the internal memory reserved for the pointer. std::vectors never downsize not even with a call to clear(). If you need to downsize a vector you will have to resort to creating another vector and swapping contents.